# How to remove blank space between background image and flex footer?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, flexbox, background-image, sticky-footer

I believe my background img is creating a blank space between it and my flexbox sticky footer. I’ve tried numerous ways, but they just create different problems so far... Can someone help? I created a placeholder image that’s the size of my original background img to recreate the problem for you! Thanks!

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/montealto/nhs4r28d/1/)

CSS:

```
.masthead {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100%;
  background:; /* ie 6 cheat */
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/3024x4032?Placeholder%27');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Sticky Footer Classes */
body
 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

html, body
 {
height: 100%;
}

#page-content {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#sticky-footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved in multiple ways,

**Method 0:** I think there is some unwanted text content before the Footer tag. If that text content is intentional then move to Method 2 else do this

Remove this below code snippet which under the `<body class="d-flex flex-column">`

```
  <div id="page-content">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h1 class="font-weight-light mt-4 text-white">Sticky Footer using Flexbox</h1>
          <p class="lead text-white-50">Use just two Bootstrap 4 utility classes and three custom CSS rules and you will have a flexbox enabled sticky footer for your website!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div id="push"></div>
  </div>
```

**Method 1:** Moving the footer towards the place where the content ends.

```
#sticky-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

or **Method 2:** In the style .css file Move the CSS background-image description defined under the class .masthead to the body

```
  background:; /* ie 6 cheat */
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/3024x4032?Placeholder');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

(use this in body not in .masthead)

Comment: OH YES- removing that extra code (your Method 0) solved the problem! I didn’t realize that I had extra code- I just assumed that it was necessary code for the sticky footer to work. Hind sight is 2020- it looks so obvious to me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This Blank space is your page-content.

You need to add this to your header:

```css
.masthead {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 56px; // your navbar height
}
```

Also add this to show your footer:

```css
#sticky-footer {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

If you want to center your content vertically add this classes to your page-content:

```html
<div id="page-content">
<div class="container text-center h-100">
<div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
```

**See the snippet:**

```css
.masthead {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: ;
  /* ie 6 cheat */
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/3024x4032?Placeholder');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  /* added */
  width: 100%;
  /* added */
}


/* Sticky Footer Classes */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#page-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#sticky-footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  z-index: 1/* added */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">website</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home
        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
      </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#blogs">Blogs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#events">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#music">Music</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!--—Full Page Image Header with Vertically Centered Content —-->
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="font-weight-light">website</h1>
        <p class="lead">2nd line</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="page-content">
  <div class="container text-center h-100">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h1 class="font-weight-light mt-4 text-white">Sticky Footer using Flexbox</h1>
        <p class="lead text-white-50">Use just two Bootstrap 4 utility classes and three custom CSS rules and you will have a flexbox enabled sticky footer for your website!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<footer id="sticky-footer" class="py-4 bg-dark text-white-50">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <small>Copyright © website</small>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: It didn’t solve the problem, but I appreciate your help and your suggestion to put an extra margin on top! I am using “mt-5” because I’m using bootstrap. that was another problem I had and was putting off to the side for later. Thanks!